# Do the Mojave or Catalina patchers support AMD PC GPUs or do you need a flashed card for this?

Tags: startup, gpu, efi

In the past, I had used dosdude1's High Sierra patcher to get macOS 10.13 on an older Mac Pro. However, the GPU in this machine is a non-flashed AMD R9 270X, so I couldn't get a boot screen and had to rely on setting the boot drive either before rebooting or setting it from command line.

Recently I tried to see if I could experiment with Mojave and the newer patcher, but I don't seem to get the video card to wake up like it did with the High Sierra patcher. Of course, being a non-flashed card I can't see the boot screen so I can't tell if the USB gets recognized or not, but after letting it sit for several minutes I don't get anything and I wonder if it is going to even work with this graphics card. With the High Sierra patcher, it would eventually come to life so I could install the AMD 5xxx/6xxx patch (though my card is a 7xxx).

Anyone know? I think Mojave or Catalina might be pushing it for the old beast at this point, but any last drops of life I can squeeze out of it before I drop money on an M1 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'older Mac Pro'… specifics would be good.

However, the R9 270X in its HD 7950 guise works fine on a 4,1 with firmware upgrade & a standard 5,1. With an unflashed card you must not use anything which needs the bootscreen - filevault or EFI/firmware lock of any sort.

The smart money was always on keeping the original video card for situations such as these, though neither the GT120 nor the HD5700 can actually run Mojave.

Anecdotally, Mojave is better than High Sierra imho, but personally I wouldn't push any cheesegrater to Catalina.

You'd be wise in any case to very carefully read [dosdude's page on Mojave](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/), as it contains a lot of caveats dependent on the precise Mac Pro model.

Comment: MacPro3,1. I've read every last comment on dosdude's page and doesn't suggest it won't work.   That being said, I know it is really old and pushing it, but I just have to /try/  ;-)

Comment: I've never tried it with the 3,1, they're still happy on El Cap. I'd keep your options open by cloning the drive before you start, then pull it out until you're sure it worked… or sure it didn't. Even if you have to clone to an HD, it's worth it for the easy ride back if you have to.

Comment: That is the idea - my primary install is on a SSD, and I cloned to an HDD which would be the guinea pig

Comment: One of the magnificent advantages of the old cheesegraters - you can get 6 drives in there before you even need to think about mounting them on the PCI. I don't even bother buying sled adaptors. On the 3,1s I  just throw SSDs loose into the optical bay & wire them down to the 2 "hidden" SATA ports ;)

Comment: FWIW, it turns out (in my experience) that you need a GPU that is either Apple supported or flashed for the Mojave patcher to work. While the High Sierra patcher would eventually bring the screen to life, this is not the case with the Mojave patcher.